# Getting a mortgage

Tags: mortgage

we own a rental property with our son. The rentals pay the house payments. After 10 years our son wants to buy his own house in another state. Do we have to pay him the whole price to buy the house or just his half. And can we get approved on our Social Security payments as income? Would we need a down payment if we already own half the house?  thanks, C

Comment: It seems like you should just work out the price with your son?  What's the question there?  Unclear what your question about Social Security means.

Comment: Hi, Carol, welcome to Money.SE. Can you please edit the question for clarity? It seems there are multiple issues packed into this one question, which might be ok, if we better understood what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking to "Do we have to pay him the whole price", you would pay him whatever the both of you agree on.  How you determine a fair price depends on a number of things.

Presumably when you bought the house for $O, you put down some down payment, $D1, and he put down some down payment, $D2.  So initially you invested ($D1/$O) and he invested ($D2/$O).  Also relevant is whether one of you was "contributing" more on the credit front - for example, in some cases the parents might contribute good credit/stable income and the child more/all of the down payment, or the inverse.  Hopefully you worked out that when you bought originally.

Then over ten years, rental payments $P+$I have been made to the mortgage, $P principal $I interest.  Ignoring $I for now, $P then might be either considered split 50/50 between the two of you, or might be split ($D1 : $D2), depending on your agreement when you bought the house, or something else.  50/50 is reasonable, so I'll suggest that here.

Also, the value of the house has changed over ten years.  Since this was across a major housing crisis, 2006 would've been near peak price - so it's possible it hasn't changed much, or even has gone down in value. Let's say the value today is $T.  Again, ($T-$O) needs to be split amongst you; let's again say it's 50/50 split, though ($D1 : $D2) split is also reasonable.  Determine this either by having an appraiser come in and do an appraisal (these are a few hundred dollars), or looking at other similar houses in the area.

Finally, some work may have been done on the house.  If you paid for it out of rental income, you might just add that to $P.  If one or the other of you paid for it out of your own pocket, then you could add that to your share; $W1 and $W2 for you and your son, respectively.  This would allow the total to be more than the value of the house, but it's costs you added, so it's reasonable.  Add to that number also if one or the other of you put significantly more sweat equity into the house - either by taking all management tasks on, mowing the lawn, fixing broken things, whatever.  How much to add is based on your agreement, either originally or now.  (Some of these costs probably aren't appropriate to add in here - regular wear and tear etc. - but others are.)

So finally, you currently have ($D1 + $P/2 + ($T-$O)/2 + $W1) interest in the house, while your son has ($D2 + $P/2 + ($T-$O)/2 + $W2) interest in the house.  Total value of the house is $T.  In order to buy your son out fairly, you might pay him his share ($D2 + $P/2 + ($T-$O)/2 + $W2).

For a real number example:

```
$O (orig. price)    = $100,000
$T (today value)    = $150,000
$P (paid principal) = $ 20,000
$D1 (your down pay) = $ 10,000
$D2 (his down pay)  = $ 10,000
$W1 (your work)     = $  5,000
$W2 (his work)      = $  5,000
------------------------------
Your value added to house: $50,000 ($45,000 of actual value + $5,000 of work)
His value added to house:  $50,000 ($45,000 of actual value + $5,000 of work)
Total left on mortgage:     $60,000
```

So, you would pay your son ($10k + .5*(20k) +  .5*(150k-100k) + $5k) = $50k.  Essentially, each of you has $50k of value in the house.  You still have $60k left on the mortgage.  You probably could get 3/4*150k ~= $110k out of a mortgage, which means you probably could just pay his share off - though of course your base mortgage would now be for $110k not $80k, meaning your payments may be higher (though at a lower interest rate hopefully, so maybe not that much higher).

---

As for the mortgage, you would want to refinance your mortgage, then, and make sure you can get at least that much out of the refinance - let the mortgage agency know that's why you're refinancing.  You would have to be able to qualify for the new mortgage on your own; we here couldn't tell you whether you could or not as we don't know the details of the house or your income.  Your lender should be able to tell you that.  You wouldn't need a new down payment, the house's equity would be that; however, you probably could only take out 75-80% of the total value of the house, so particularly if the house has depreciated in value because of the crash, that might make it hard to do so.